Moving block bootstrap to get CI around first derivative of trend
I have a time series and I want to know  the rate of change of the nonlinear trend component. To do this I want to take the first derivative of the trend but I need a confidence interval around it. I thought one way might be to do an STL and then use a moving block bootstrap on the residuals  to generate a bootstrapped time series, repeating the decomposition on each and calculating the derivative of the trend each time - allowing me to bootstrap a CI around the derivative?
Is that a sound approach? Note I don't care about forecasting, just the historical data - is bootstrapping still useful here? And if so, how many bootstraps would be appropriate?

There must be multiple typos in "tmrate if change if the nonlinear trend component."  Please fix them so we can understand your question.

Okay.  But what bootstrap are you proposing?  Time series are not easy to bootstrap correctly because there's no way to resample accurately under any model except iid.  In fact, it's unclear what you want to estimate, because the very definition of "nonlinear" is equivalent to "the rate of change is either undefined or not constant." What, then, do you mean by this "rate of change"?

I think the continous first derivative of the trend component tells me it's rate of change, right? I'm happy with that part I think.  I'm aware bootstrapping time series is tricky, my understanding is moving block bootstrap is one approach designed to address the non iid problem. But it seems always used in forecasting as far as I'm come across  - I haven't seen it specifically for getting a CI around the trend component and the derivative of the trend, but I don't know why that would be different. But I'm not knowledgeable.
